# Can I set 1 group to be in the middle of the artboard without changing the position of the object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I design a calendar in Illustrator, I create lots of groups consisting of numbers. I grouped by month. When pressing center on the alignment button, all objects are centered, not by group. How do I center all groups?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply *Group* things - as in the *Illustrator command* to Group. - Select all the objects for a single month and choose `Object > Group` from the menu.

When using the align features, Groups are seen as a *single object* and will be aligned as such.

So... Group Jan, then group Feb, then Mar, then Apr, etc. You can then choose to align the months, as a whole, to each other.

[image]

---

From your images.. the first image appears as though *nothing* was technically Grouped (in Illustrator terms).

Here's a link explaining how Groups work in Illustrator. It May be helpful: https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=435193&seqNum=4

Comment: After I use the group selection tool, I can move group to the center, but if I press the small circle on the layer, it will create an effect like the first image. Thanks!

Comment: @group selection tool does not make groups it selects objects under groups. So yes aligning group members should behave like that. (note illustrator interprets selecting all in groups as being the whole group so this may behave somewhat inconsitent but working as intended)

Comment: @tukangdonlod if you look at the Layers Panel.. are there actual `<Group>` items? I'm referring to what Illustrator has set as a Group, not merely a collection of items close to each other.

Comment: For the record.. in more than 35 years of Illustrator use I have **never once** touched the Group Selection Tool. It's a pointless tool that has no unique operation.

Comment: Hi, that’s a very kind of you for doing that. You helped me!